# How can I start moving elements when it reach the top of my window?

Tags: jquery, css

I am floating this elements on scroll but I want to start floating when it reach the top of window. Does anyone has any idea?

https://jsfiddle.net/eoopvgmc/13/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.ads').css({
      'top': $(window).scrollTop() + 'px'
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: So you mean, currently, the floating elements scroll right away (starting at the top of the page). When do you want the floating elements to start moving?

Comment: soon as the elements are going to reach the top of the window not when I start scrolling

Comment: So they should only move when "top_banner" and "main_content" top borders meet the top of the window?

Comment: exactly, thats right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this little piece of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var offset = $('.ads').offset().top, top;
    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        top = $(window).scrollTop() < offset ? '0' : $(window).scrollTop() - offset + 'px';
        $('.ads').css({
            'top': top
        });
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/eoopvgmc/16/)